# How to import actionscript library and call function?

Tags: actionscript-3, data-structures

I need to develop something with data structure and how do I import the library as3ds (http://code.google.com/p/polygonal/wiki/DataStructures) and call the function of the library? It is in swc file format for the new version. While the older as3ds is in as format. I've no idea how to call using the swc. Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just place the .swc file where ever you want (usually in your own developer library) and target its path in ActionScript 3.0 Settings of Flash CS5:  File > ActionScript Settings... (see attached screen shot).

you could also just place it in with your other library swcs.  Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/

if it's a component, create a folder for it and place the folder in the components folder:  Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/Components/[image]